# C++ Modulus Operator Understanding

Tags: c++

I am just starting out programming and reading thru C++ Programming Principles and Practice. I am currently doing the Chapter 3 exercises and do not understand why this code I wrote works. Please help explain.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
  cout<<"Hello, User\n""Please enter a number (Followed by the 'Enter'     key):";
  int number=0;
  cin>> number;
  if (number%2) {
    cout<<"Your number is an odd number!";
  } else {
    cout<<"Your number is an even number\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you confused about? you need to ask a specific question. "explain the operation of this entire program to me" is too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: Two important concepts: 1) the result of any `n % 2` is either 0 or 1.  2) Any integer expression that evaluates to "0" is considered `false`; any non-zero integer (including - but not limited - to "1") is `true`.  Q: Does that answer your question?

Comment: And your book does not explain the code you got from it? Get a better book!

Comment: Don't get why the question is receiving downvotes for being too broad. There are 13 lines of code, most of which is whitespace or something similar, and, based on the title, it is incredibly obvious which part of the program the asker does not understand -- the only part involving a modulus (the conditionals). Seeing as the answer to the question entails knowledge of both the workings behind the modulus operator and c++'s capabilities of interpreting 1 and 0 as true and false respectively, this is a great question.

Comment: @Nerdizzle: If the question contained only some of the extra information in your comment, then it would not have been downvoted, I guess. *"do not understand why this code I wrote works"* is **never** a sufficient, self-contained problem description.

Answer (score 3):

When `number` is odd, `number%2` is `1`.

```
if (number%2) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (1) {
```

Hence, you get the output from the line

```
cout<<"Your number is an odd number!";
```

When `number` is even, `number%2` is `0`.

```
if (number%2) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (0) {
```

Hence, you get the output from the line

```
cout<<"Your number is an even number\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator simply determines the remainder of the corresponding division problem. For instance, `2 % 2` returns **0** as `2 / 2` is 1 with a remainder of **0**.

In your code, any even number entered will return a 0 as all even numbers are, by definition, divisible by 2 (meaning `<any even number> % 2 == 0`)

Likewise, any odd number entered will return 1 (for instance, `7 % 2 == 1` as 7 / 2 has a remainder of 1).

In c++, like in many programming languages, numeral values can be treated as booleans such that 0 relates to false while other numbers (depending on the language) relate to true (1 is, as far as I know, universally true no matter the programming language).

In other words, an odd number input would evaluate `number % 2` to 1, meaning true. So `if (number % 2),` we know that the input number is odd. Otherwise, `number % 2` must be false, meaning 0, which means that the input number is even.

Answer (score 0):

"if" statements works on boolean values. Let's remember that boolean values are represented by "false" and "true", but in reality, it's all about the binary set of Z2 containing {0, 1}. "false" represents "0" and "true" represents "1" (or some people in electronics interpret them as "off/on")

So, yeah, behind the curtains, "if" statements are looking for 0 or 1. The modulus operator returns the rest of a / b. When you input any number and divide it by 2, you are gonna get a rest of 0 or 1 being it pair or an odd number.

So that's why it works, you will always get a result of 0 or 1 which are false and true by doing that operation that way.

Answer (score 0):

think of modulus in terms of this:
while (integer A is bigger than integer B,) 
A = A - B;
return A

for example, 9%2 -> 9-2=7-2=5-2=3-2=1
9%2=1;

the statement if (number%2) is what is called a boolean comparison (true false). Another way to write this statement identically is if(number%2 != 0) or if(number%2 != false) since false and zero are equivocal. You're taking the return value of the modulus operator function (a template object we will assume is an integer) and inserting it into an if statement that executes if the input does not equal zero. If statements execute if the input is -5,9999999,1-- anything but zero. So, if (2) would be true. if(-5) would also be true. if(0) would be false. if(5%2) would be 1 = true. if(4%2) would be if(0) = false. If it is true, the code in the body of the if statement is executed.